# Inserting decimals into integer data type column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why are values that I insert into the table always are rounding down?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE BI.DBO.table
( 
    some_value int
);

INSERT INTO BI.DBO.table 
VALUES (15), (10.23), (7.7), (7.45553);

SELECT *
FROM BI.DBO.table
```

Results are:

```
15 
10 
 7 
 7
```

Why is the value `7.7` rounded down to 7, and not up to 8?

Comment: This is truncation, not rounding. *Don't* try to insert decimals in an integer column. Use the type you actually need.

Comment: It is not "rounded".  It is truncated.  That is how SQL defines what to do.

Comment: **Never** rely on implicit data type conversion

Comment: So independently what value is after a decimal point it will be truncated to value before decimal? Right? @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql wil truncate your number in this case.
If you don't want to change your data type and round it, just use the function `ROUND(value, decimals)`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES
(ROUND(7.7654321,0)) --INSERTED VALUE = 8
```

Answer (score -2):

make data type of some value column as decimal